# Formatting Excel column using Currency Format

Tags: php, excel, formatting

I'm using an old `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` script, that I don't have the right to edit it, *(Written by John McNamara in 2002)* to export Excel files.

To format column data, I have to pass cell format as an array :

```
$format_tab['Cell'] = $workbook->addformat (array (
    bold         => 1,
    color       => 'black',
    font         => 'Tahoma',
    italic    => 0,
    size         => 9,
    align       => 'center',
));
```

Now, I need to format the cell's data as Currency, so I used this pattern:

```
num_format => '_(#,##0.00_)';
```

This gave me this output :

```
 Input |   Output
-------|--------------
123456 | 123456,000.00
```

But my desired output is `123,456.00`.

How can I get that format ?

Comment: What is the format of the cells before you try to change it (i.e. the 'input')?

Comment: It's a normal string, like `123456`.

Comment: Can you select one of those cells and run the following line of code `msgbox Selection.NumberFormat` and let us know what it says?

Comment: How can I run that code ?

Comment: It's just [VBA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155), you say 123456 is a normal string, but we need to know what Excel thinks it is: a string or a number.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm using Ubuntu LibreOffice. Anyway, when I click on the cell to edit, it shows `'123456` (note the single quote)

Comment: Ah, can you edit the tags of you question to reflect that?

Comment: That apostrophe at the start forces LibreOffice to read the rest of the cell as text, it really shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad, I appreciate your help! It's just pattern problem, and I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue using this pattern :

```
num_format => '_(* #,##0.00_)'
```

This will give me `123,456.00`, but note that, in `Excel`, the output format depends from the local setting of the user.

So, if you set your local to `France`, the output will be `123 456,00`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you remove the parentheses and underscores?

```
num_format => '#,##0.00'
```

Comment: No, no change !